# How to speed up search including special character alternatives and nested loops (Python/Django webapp)?

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-itertools

I have three loops nested in a python/django webapp backend. `all_recommended_services` has all the service info I need to go through. `alternatives` has the search criteria entered in the search bar, including all special character alternatives (for example: `u` is substituted with `ú`, `ö` with `ő` and so on...). Finally, the loop `for value in alternative:` goes through all search words individually split by empty space.
There are search keyword combinations which yield millions of alternatives, which totally kills the webapp. Is there an efficient way to speed this up? I tried to look into `itertools.product` to use cartesian, but it didn't really help me avoid more loops or speed up the process. Any help is much appreciated!

```
    for service in all_recommended_services:

    county_str = get_county_by_id(all_counties, service['county_id'])

    for alternative in alternatives:
        something_found = False

        for value in alternative:
            something_found = search_in_service(service, value, county_str)

            if not something_found:
                break

        if something_found:
            if not service in recommended_services:
                recommended_services.append(service)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are searching, I will suggest this package named [Django-haystack](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/). It is easy to use and is highly customizable to fit your needs. Since you didn't include more detail, I can't provide a more detailed demo, but the documentation is comprehensive.